# Index pandas dataframe rows 4 at a time

Tags: python, pandas

I want to to be able to something along the lines of:

```
for i in range(0, len(df), 4):
    curr = pd.DataFrame()
    vcch = int(df.loc[i, 'IN_CUSTOM_SELECT'])
    icch = int(df.loc[i+1, 'IN_CUSTOM_SELECT'])
    vccl = int(df.loc[i+2, 'IN_CUSTOM_SELECT'])
    iccl = int(df.loc[i+3, 'IN_CUSTOM_SELECT'])
    idlpwr = (vcch * icch) + (vccl * iccl)
    idlpwr = idlpwr / (10**6)
```

where I do some calculations based on the specific values of columns in combinations of rows of 4.

Comment: Do you really want to do this just for one specific value of `i`? Or do you want to do it for multiple values of `i`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just working with a regular autonumbered index, one easy option is to reshape your data and use `pandas` vectorized operations for the math:

```
In [196]: df = pd.DataFrame({'IN_CUSTOM_SELECT': np.random.random(24)})

In [197]: reshaped = df.set_index([df.index.map(lambda x: x // 4), df.index.map(lambda x: x % 4)]).unstack()['IN_CUSTOM_SELECT']

In [198]: reshaped['idlpwr'] = ((reshaped[0] * reshaped[1]) + (reshaped[2] * reshaped[3])) / 10**6

In [199]: reshaped
Out[199]:
          0         1         2         3        idlpwr
0  0.788758  0.853356  0.627796  0.355143  8.960487e-07
1  0.312111  0.602934  0.908984  0.046183  2.301622e-07
2  0.842201  0.507629  0.541432  0.592680  7.484218e-07
3  0.506601  0.605108  0.497627  0.362006  4.866923e-07
4  0.308097  0.991945  0.822433  0.272082  5.293851e-07
5  0.573716  0.852356  0.009606  0.961437  4.982462e-07
```